# Tkinter image stream

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python and I am trying to make a program that displays a sequence of screenshots one after another indefinitely to stream the screen of an iOS device. I am trying to recreate the Python program used in the [Trustjacking demo by Symantec to simulate the videojacking attack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TWCSfBhtss).

This is the code I have so far

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import os

  while True:

    def stream():

      root = Tk()

      os.system("sudo idevicescreenshot test.jpg | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null 2>&1")

      width = 500
      height = 700
      img = Image.open("/Desktop/test.jpg")
      img = img.resize((width,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
      photoImg =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
      b = Button(root,image=photoImg, width=500)
      b.pack()
      os.system("rm -rf /Desktop/test.jpg")
      root.mainloop()
    stream()
```

But it only moves to the next image when you close the Tkinter window. The program in the demo cycles through the screenshots without closing the Tkinter window so, closing and reopening the window is not an option. I cannot figure out how to take the screenshots and then cycle through them one after another in one Tkinter window to create a stream. Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Soutcast and welcome to StackOverflow.

Use the `Widget.after`-Method (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) instead of a `while`-loop. If you call `after` inside the callback again you can achieve something similar to a `while True`.

Here's why:

A GUI-based application behaves differently from a console-application as it has to react to user-input. To be able to handle user input, tkinter blocks the thread where you call `Widget.mainloop` to handle events like button-clicks and so on until the window closes.

The `after`-function can tell the running event loop to run the given function after a given amount of time.

---

Edit as requested by Soutcast:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import os

root = Tk()
b = Button(root,image=photoImg, width=500)
b.pack()

def update_image():
  os.system("sudo idevicescreenshot test.jpg | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null 2>&1")

  width = 500
  height = 700
  img = Image.open("/Desktop/test.jpg")
  img = img.resize((width,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
  photoImg =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

  os.system("rm -rf /Desktop/test.jpg")
  b['image'] = photoImg
  root.after(1000, update_image)

root.after(1, update_image)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi @StuxCrystal, could you please repost the code with you recommended edits included as i have tried using the after widget but it just opens two tkinter windows and errors out "(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist"

Comment: If this helps you, please mark this question as answered. If not, please add a comment explaining why.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @StuxCrystal but when I try to run your code I get an error that states `photoImg is not defined`. I think this is because you are trying to set the image as photoImg `image=photoImg` before the value of photoImg has been set. Could you please help me fix this.